# asp.net core data protection : An exception was thrown while deserializing the token

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis, kestrel-http-server

Im running asp.net core on a webfarm using redis as dataprotection storage.

my app is under heavy load so i get following error constantly from redis :

> Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 9, queue: 1448, qu: 0, qs: 1448, qc: 0,
>   wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 65536, ar: 0, clientName: xxxx

The way redis was initialized at startup.cs using [microsoft recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers) was

```
var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("<URI>");
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");
```

so aftre reading some articles regarding not redis being thread safe i change redis initialization to be thread safe as suggested at [azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache#connect-to-cache) and [here](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/setting-up-a-connection-with-stackexchange-redis/)

```
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => {
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("mycache.redis.cache.windows.net,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=...");
});

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection {
    get {
        return lazyConnection.Value;
    }
}
```

but now the problem is that every second or so i get the following errors:

> The antiforgery token could not be decrypted. --->
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {xxxxxxx}
>   was not found in the key ring.

or

> An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.

or

> Error unprotecting the session cookie.

or

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {xxxxx}
>   was not found in the key ring.

what's the problem and what should i do?

should i change initialization again? but then app will halt under heavy load.

**Updated**

**More Info:**

i have accidentally used a wrong connection string for redis and again change it to correct one.

Of course there could be other bugs that cause this error.

How can i handle and mitigate this error now?

The error is clear and may be it is not possible to reproduce it on another dev env.

But there should be a way to handle this kind of error.

Comment: There is no way anyone can reproduce your problem with the code you provided. The errors don't have necessarily anything to do with using Redis. It is most likely your implementation not handling errors or non-existing keys gracefully.

Comment: how can i handle non-existing keys gracefully?

Comment: for more info i have accidentally used a wrong connection string for redis and again change it to correct one.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the data protection error, you can run a PowerShell script. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/DataProtection/dev/Provision-AutoGenKeys.ps1. you just need to run the script as Administrator and provide the app pool name

Comment: Appears to be moved to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/master/src/DataProtection/Provision-AutoGenKeys.ps1